# Use dataframe created in R codechunk in ojs codechunk in quarto

Tags: r, observablehq, quarto

I'm completely new to using `quarto`. But one thing I wonder is if there is any chance to use a dataframe created "on the fly" in the quarto document in an observable (ojs) chunk, instead of maybe writing it out as CSV and reading it in? I guess there is no way at all, but you never know:)

So something like this:

```
df = data.frame(
  x = 1:10,
  y = 2:11
)
```

```
{
 // somehow get access to the df
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use a dataframe for example in a next chunk without overwriting in the next chunk?

Comment: My intention was more to create the data in R and wrangle in in JS (without writing it to disk)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ojs_define()` function to make data processed in Python or R available to {ojs} cells (this function should be called in the R or Python cell).

See more here in the [Quarto Documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/interactive/ojs/data-sources.html).